# Как добавить сообщение пользователя телеграм бота в таблицу Excel?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, excel

```
if call.data == '1':
    mes = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'сумма?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(mes, test)

def test(message):
    writeExel.wp['A2'].value = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'done')
```

#там много кода, удалил все лишнее.

Суть: из кол меню выбираю дату, бот спрашивает сумму, я ввожу и ожидаю, что `bot.register_next_step_handler` считает ее и кинет в `def test`, сообщение 'done' отправляет, данные в таблицу не вписывает. `WriteExel.wp` - путь к экселевскому листу.

Comment: Больше информации надо. Какой пакет используете для работы с excel?

Comment: openpyxl и все.